# Nginx proxy special uri to socket.io

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, proxy, socket.io

I want to use nginx to proxy url like `https://api.example.com/wss/...` to many nodejs servers(socket.io):

```
upstream websocket {
        ip_hash;            
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082;
}

location /wss/
        {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

After this , I want to attach my service like `"wss://api.example.com/wss/"`
But when this request to nodejs servers , It will not request `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` but `http://127.0.0.1:8080/wss/` , and socket.io will not work in this URI .
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://websocket/;` (with a trailing `/`). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard Smith said in comments , it did works!

Thanks!